# Recover MySQL MyISAM BAK files

Tags: mysql

I had some hard disk issue on my server and I noticed a MySQL table is missing lots of rows (5k instead of about 200M).

In the MySQL directory I have a BAK file for that table : mytable-160115203241.BAK. It is 15Gb, so I guess the lost rows could be in it.

I read from [the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisam-start.html) where does this file come from :

> If the automatic recovery value includes BACKUP, the recovery process
>   creates files with names of the form tbl_name-datetime.BAK.

But I can't find anywhere how to recover data from this BAK file.
Anyone knows ?